# Why is Intellij IDEA SVN history not displaying some revisions, which are displayed in Tortoise SVN log?

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, tortoisesvn

The SVN history of a project in IntelliJ IDEA is missing some revisions, which are present in the Tortoise SVN log.

[image: SVN history]
As you can see in the picture in Tortoise SVN the next revision after 24220 is **24216**, but in Intellij IDEA the next revision is **23650**.

(To display the history in Intellij IDEA I right-click in the project window  on the project root and select from the menu "Subversion > Show History". For the Tortoise SVN log I right-click on the base folder of the project and select "Tortoise SVN > Show log".)

Why is Intellij IDEA Subversion history not displaying these revisions?

**EDIT:**

r23650 was a commit directly to the branch. Could it be that this revision is not visible in the history in Intellij IDEA, because it made changes to a file not directly under the project root?

Comment: Do you use the same working copy in TortoiseSVN and in IDEA? Run `svn update` in IDEA.

Comment: It is exactly the same project and the same files. It should be the same working copy, shouldn't it?

Comment: it can be a different working copy in different location on your disk.

Comment: In this case it's the same location on the disk. So it should be the same working copy, right? (Sincere question. I have no clue if it could be different working copies.)

Comment: Please check if all revisions are shown on "repository" tab in Version Control Tool Window.

Comment: r24220 is a merge. Perhaps IntelliJ IDEA is displaying the source revisions too (as Tortoise does when you check "Include merged revisions"). Can you please verify that?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for the tip, but IntelliJ IDEA is not displaying the source revisions. It's missing some revisions, which were commits directly to the branch (eg. r23650).

Comment: @y.bedrov How do I check if all revisions are shown on "repository" tab in Version Control Tool Window? Currently the setting "Changelists to cache intially:" is set to 500. There are no filters set and it's grouped by date. Funny enough, it's showing different revisions as in the history (e.g. revision 24220 is missing).

Comment: I figured it out now... Intellij IDEA SVN history is only showing the changes made to the selected folder or files directly located in that folder. Changes made to files in subfolders are NOT visible. To see such changes you have to use "Browse changes..." (also located in the context menu under Subversion).
Sorry for bothering you for this and thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intellij IDEA SVN history is only showing the commits made to the selected folder or files directly located in that folder. Commits which modified files in subfolders are NOT visible. To see all commits made in the branch you have to use "Browse changes..." - located in the context menu under "Subversion".

[image: "Browse changes" in the context menu under "Subversion"]

Answer (score 1):

For those having problems with not displaying complete history in **Repository** tab, first click on **Clear** and finally **Refresh** (pressing Refresh only does nothing).